# LookUpEdit DisplayFormat FormatString

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, lookup

I'am having simple problem with [DevExpress LookUpEdit](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic) DisplayFormat. I want to achieve results in lookUpEdit like:
Document type (*.doc)

Document type (*.docx)

```
const string defaultExtensionsList = "doc;docx;xlsx;xls;pdf;txt";
//...
var column = new LookUpColumnInfo("Column", "Extensions")
{
    Visible = true,
    //FormatType = FormatType.Custom,
    //FormatString ="Document type (*.{0})",
    Alignment = HorzAlignment.Near
};
ExtensionsLookup.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Custom;
ExtensionsLookup.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "Document type (*.{0})";
ExtensionsLookup.Properties.EditFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Custom;
ExtensionsLookup.Properties.EditFormat.FormatString = "Document type (*.{0})";
ExtensionsLookup.Properties.Columns.Add(column);

var bindingList = defaultExtensionsList.Split(';').ToList();
ExtensionsLookup.Properties.DataSource = bindingList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following trick ([RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.GetNotInListValue](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemLookUpEdit_GetNotInListValuetopic) event):

```
const string defaultExtensionsList = "doc;docx;xlsx;xls;pdf;txt";
//...
var columnID = new LookUpColumnInfo("Column", "IDs") { Visible = false };
var columnToDisplay = new LookUpColumnInfo("Display", "Extensions");

lookUpEdit.Properties.Columns.AddRange(new LookUpColumnInfo[] { columnID, columnToDisplay });
lookUpEdit.Properties.ValueMember = "Column";
lookUpEdit.Properties.DisplayMember = "Display";
lookUpEdit.Properties.TextEditStyle = TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor;
lookUpEdit.Properties.GetNotInListValue += OnGetNotInListValue;

var bindingList = defaultExtensionsList.Split(';').ToList();
lookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource = bindingList;
//...
void OnGetNotInListValue(object sender, GetNotInListValueEventArgs e) {
    if(e.FieldName == "Display")
        e.Value = string.Format("Document type (*.{0})",
            ((IList<string>)lookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource)[e.RecordIndex]);
}
```

Comment: hanks. This is ALMOST what I need. var columnToDisplay = new LookUpColumnInfo("Display", "Extensions"); ExtensionsLookup.Properties.Columns.Add(columnToDisplay); ExtensionsLookup.Properties.GetNotInListValue += OnGetNotInListValue; Why almost? EditValue is not formatted accordingly :) I WILL Accept :P

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, LookUpEdit doesn't support this functionality.

I would simply build a List with values "Document type (*.docx)", "Documentype (*.xy)" and bind it to the control.

Something like

```
var types = defaultExtensionsList.Split(';').Select(s => "DocumentType (*." + s + ")").ToList();
```

Comment: I know but I need to be able to manipulate with that data (delete, add unique) so I thought this could be done via FormatString. This way I don't need to manage a Dictionary or two lists.